# Hive SQL: Filtering out rows that contain duplicate values for a specific column

Tags: sql, filter, hiveql

I have a hive table with the following data: (first row is header)

```
session,ts,status,color
a,1,new,red
a,2,check,blue
a,3,new,green
a,4,amount,blue
a,5,end,blue
b,1,new,red
b,2,bottle,blue
b,3,end,blue
c,4,check,blue
```

I'm having trouble writing a sql query that meets the following criteria:
1) all rows for sessions that contains a status of new. 
2) if the sessions contains multilpe values for status=new, only remove the first one

The output would be

```
a,1,new,red
a,2,check,blue
a,4,amount,blue
a,5,end,blue
b,1,new,red
b,2,bottle,blue
b,3,end,blue
```

rows `a,3,new,green` and `c,4,check,blue` are omitted.

I've written this query which does indeed do the trick if you are only looking at the `session`, `ts` and `status` columns, but I don't like the second query as it has a group-by in it

```
select  session, ts, status from mp_logon3
where status!='new'
and session in (select distinct a.session from mp_logon3 a 
where a.status = 'new'
) 
union
select session, min(ts), status from mp_logon3
where status='new'
and session in (select distinct b.session from mp_logon3 b
where b.status = 'new'
)
group by session, status
```

However, as soon as you add the `color` column, it falls apart. (You get both rows for session=a and status=new. One for green and one for red.

```
select  session, ts, status, flavor from mp_logon3
where status!='new'
and session in (select distinct a.session from mp_logon3 a 
where a.status = 'new'
) 
union
select session, min(ts), status, flavor from mp_logon3
where status='new'
and session in (select distinct b.session from mp_logon3 b
where b.status = 'new'
)
group by session, status, flavor
```

Lastly, is there a better way to write this query as a whole. Maybe one without the union?

Comment: Which DBMS? (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL etc)

Comment: Whoops, thanks for the comment. It is Hive Sql. I have added that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the HiveQL solution for your problem

```
WITH sessions
AS (SELECT DISTINCT session
    FROM mp_logon3
    WHERE STATUS = 'new')
,logons
AS (SELECT session
        ,ts
        ,STATUS
        ,color
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY session
            ,STATUS ORDER BY ts
            ) AS r_num
    FROM mp_logon3)
SELECT l.*
FROM logons l
INNER JOIN sessions s ON (s.session = l.session)
WHERE l.STATUS <> 'new'
    OR l.r_num = 1
ORDER BY l.session
    ,l.ts;
```

Answer (score 1):

If using Teradata SQL:

```
select  session, ts, status, color
from mp_logon3
where status='new'
and session in (select distinct a.session from mp_logon3 a 
where a.status = 'new'
) 
qualify row_number() over (partition by session,status order by ts)=1
union
select  session, ts, status, flavor from mp_logon3
where status!='new'
and session in (select distinct a.session from mp_logon3 a 
where a.status = 'new'
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is actually hive sql. I have specified that now.